# Program terminates with no error message

Tags: java, terminate

This is my code that I had to use for a question. I am supposed to look for words in the command line in Eclipse by typing java Spell a and getting all word outprinted in the console that starts with a from a local text file. My program terminates for no apparent reason:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Spell {
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Dennis\\words.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        String word = fileScanner.next();
        if(word.startsWith(args[0])) {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: are there items in the file beginning with 'a'?

Comment: given that your program is supposed to terminate, I would expect it does exactly what you've written: read the file, finds no strings that start with the first letter you passed as `args[0]`, and finishes cleanly.

Comment: How you are running this program ?

Comment: The words all begin with a. I am just running the program with the run command in eclipse. What does args[0] do exactly in this case?

Comment: are you supplying the desired argument in the Eclipse run command?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this program as `java Spell garfield` then the `args[0]` will contain garfield in the file if any word will match with garfield then your print statement will be executed otherwise not.You have to provide run time argument in `ecclipse` for running your program and then you will be able to see the actual out put you want.[image]

rightclick in your `Class` contaning `main method` select `run as->run configuration` in the `tab (x)=Arguments` give your argument then run and see below is the screen shot for this

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, right-click on your java file -> Run as -> Run configurations -> Tab Arguments, in programme arguments, enter a. If there is no argument entered, you should get an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" at the line

```
if(word.startsWith(args[0])) {
```

I would suggest putting a break-point on the line

```
String word = fileScanner.next();
```

and then Debug.
So that you can verify the words scanned by the programme and check if the arg[0] is what you entered.

I have run your programme with words.txt like

```
asdf
bsdf
csdf
dsdf
```

and argument `c`, it prints out

```
csdf
```

correctly.

Comment: Ah yeah I tried just typing the word in the command line and now it works. Thank you very much!